# how display automated data on the display items in oracle forms

Tags: oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a code in the ADD Button , for displaying stored data(in the table) on the CONTROL Block 
the below code is working fine but i am not getting serial_no on the Block

```
COMMIT_FORM;

Declare 
  Cursor Cur_BILL_DETAILS 
   Is Select code , item_name , qty ,  amount
        From APPS.XXC_BILL_DETAILS 
       Where Bill_no = :bill_no; 
Begin 
  Go_Block('CONTROL');                 
  Open Cur_BILL_DETAILS; 
  Loop 
    Fetch Cur_BILL_DETAILS Into  :CONTROL.CODE , 
                                 :CONTROL.item_name , 
                                 :CONTROL.qty , 
                                 :CONTROL.amount; 
    Exit When Cur_BILL_DETAILS %Notfound; 
    Next_Record; 
  End Loop; 
  Close Cur_BILL_DETAILS; 
 First_Record; 
End;
```

And i created the pre-insert on the CONTROL Block(non-database) as below for displaying  Serial_no as

```
declare
  v_no number;
Begin
 select xxc_sno.nextval into v_no from dual;
 :CONTROL.SNO:=v_no;
end;
```

Suppose ,

I am inserting into code, item_name,qty,amount and commited the record , the above ADD Button code worked fine.

The Pre-insert code not generating and displaying the no's as 1,2,3..

Ex:

```
  Code    item   qty  Amount 
  ----    ----   ---  -----
   A       AA     1   10
   B       BB     1   20
```

and click on the ADD Button, it is saved the inserted 2 records and goes the below(next , control block), display the Stored Records on the Control Block

```
     Sno     Code    item   qty  Amount 
     ----    ----    ----   ---  -----
      1         A      AA     1   10
      2         B      BB     1   20
```

But the pre-insert trigger is not generating serial no's as 1,2 ,3 etc..(not effecting)

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms `PRE-INSERT` triggers fire during the posting of data to a base table block.  A control block does not have a base table so `PRE-INSERT` will never fire.  I am not sure (my Forms knowledge is rusty) but you may want to look at using a `WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` trigger instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply Tony , you mean WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE on control for Sno?

Comment: Yes I did - this should populate SNO when the control block record is created.